# Scala Collection Specific Implementation

Tags: scala, collections

Say I have some data in a Seq in Scala 2.10.2, e.g:

```
scala> val data = Seq( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
data: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Now, I perform some operations and convert it to a Map

```
scala> val pairs = data.map( i => i -> i * 2 )
pairs: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,4), (3,6), (4,8), (5,10))

scala> val pairMap = pairs.toMap
pairMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 10, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 8)
```

Now say, for performance reasons, I'd like `pairMap` to use the `HashMap` implementation of `Map`. What's the best way to achieve this?

Ways I've considered:

1. Casting:

   ```
   pairMap.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int]]
   ```

   This seems a bit horrible.
2. Manually converting:

   ```
   var hm = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int]()
   pairMap.foreach( p => hm += p )
   ```

   But this isn't very functional.
3. Using the builder

   ```
   scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int]( pairMap.toSeq:_* )
   ```

   This works, but it's not the most readable piece of code.

Is there a better way that I'm missing? If not, which of these is the best approach?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting bit: it already is an immutable HashMap.

```
scala> val data = Seq( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
data: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val pairs = data.map( i => i -> i * 2 )
pairs: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,4), (3,6), (4,8), (5,10))

scala> val pairMap = pairs.toMap
pairMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = 
      Map(5 -> 10, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 8)

scala> pairMap.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = 
      class scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap
```

Note: casting to be a hashmap doesn't at all change the underlying thing. If you wanted to guarantee building a hashmap (or some specific type), then I'd recommend this:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.collection.immutable

scala> val pairMap = immutable.HashMap(pairs: _*)
pairMap: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = 
      Map(5 -> 10, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 8)
```

If you're looking for performance improvements you should look into using a `mutable.HashMap` or `java.util.HashMap`. Most of scala's collections are out-performed by the native `java.util` collections.

Comment: OK, thanks. The performance requirement was an example; in general, is this the best way to obtain a more specific collection?

Comment: Yes it is. Though, you should always pass around the most generic interface in your codebase to avoid lots of unnecessary change when you choose a different underlying type. (per Twitter's Effective Scala: http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/)

Comment: Naturally. Just sometimes, using a `SortedMap` can be useful in a given situation, for example!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine

- An explicit result type
- `map`: Map key and value into a tuple
- `breakOut`: "Break out" the sequence of tuples from `map`, and create the target type directly

like this

```
val s = Seq.range(1, 6)

val m: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int, Int] = 
  s.map(n => (n, n * n))(scala.collection.breakOut)
```

which creates the `HashMap` on-the-fly without an intermediate map.

By using `breakOut` and the explicit result type an appropriate builder for `map` is chosen, and your target type is created directly